# Travel from Hanoi to Chiang Mai via BKK by Qatar/Bangkok airways. What is the luggage allowance, how many pieces and dimensions?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, qatar-airways

Travel with Qatar from Hanoi to Bangkok what is the baggage allowance, how many pieces, and what dimensions?

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE. What is your fare type?

Answer (score 1):

[Qatar Airways](http://www.qatarairways.com/uk/en/baggage.page)

**Checked baggage allowance**

First Class
50kg (110lb) and a maximum dimension of 406cm (160in)

Business Class
40kg (88lb) and a maximum dimension of 406cm (160in)

Economy Class
30kg (66lb) and a maximum dimension of 406cm (160in)

```
Maximum dimension = length + height + width
Baggage allowances may vary according to route and cabin class. Please check the exact baggage regulations printed on your ticket.
Excess baggage charges may apply if you exceed the weight and/or piece allowances. Contact your local Qatar Airways office for more information.
A single piece of checked baggage must not weigh more than 32kg (70lb). Any bags weighing more than 32kg (70lb) must be broken down such that each piece weighs less than 32kg (70lb).
If your journey includes travel on an airline other than Qatar Airways, including a Qatar Airways codeshare flight operated by another airline, that operating airline may offer you a lower baggage allowance. You are advised to check with that airline on their allowance.
```

**Hand Baggage**

First Class
Two pieces, not to exceed a total weight of 15kg (33lb)

Business Class
Two pieces, not to exceed a total weight of 15kg (33lb)

Economy Class
One piece, not to exceed 7 kg (15lb)

```
Maximum hand baggage dimensions are 50x37x25cm (20x15x10in) each
Personal items such as one ladies handbag or one small briefcase, walking sticks, cameras, and duty-free items purchased on the day of your flight are not counted towards your hand baggage allowance.
Laptops and laptop bags have to fit within your hand baggage allowance.
```

**Liquids and gels in hand baggage**

You may carry liquids, gels, pastes, and aerosols in containers up to 100ml (3.4oz) in your hand baggage. Containers larger than 100ml will not be accepted even if only partly filled. Your containers must be carried in a transparent, resealable, quart- or liter-sized bag no larger than 20x20cm (8x8in). All items must fit comfortably in the plastic bag.

You are required to produce your transparent bag of liquids separately for security screening. There are no restrictions on baby foods and medication. However, you may be required to present a prescription for medication you want to take onboard.